# Blogger feed from RSS on website

Tags: javascript, rss, blogger

I'm trying to get posts from a blog to show on my website via RSS/JavaScript. I can successfully get the title and link to posts to pull in, but nothing else will show when I try to get the actual post content. I feel like I'm missing something simple although after reading through Google's API docs for the last two days I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("feeds", "1");

  var feedContainer=document.getElementById("blog-feed")
  var feedURL="http://MYBLOGTITLE.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss"
  var postsReturned=2
  var rssoutput="<ul>"

  function rssFeedSetup(){
    var pullFeed=new google.feeds.Feed(feedURL)
    pullFeed.setNumEntries(postsReturned) 
    pullFeed.load(showFeed) 
  }

  function showFeed(result){
    if (!result.error){
      var thefeeds=result.feed.entries
      for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++)
      rssoutput+="<li><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a>" + thefeeds[i].content +"</li>"
      rssoutput+="</ul>"
      feedContainer.innerHTML=rssoutput
    }
    else
      alert("There was an error loading the blog posts.")
  }

  window.onload=function(){
    rssFeedSetup()
  }
</script>
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the content this way, or am I approaching this completely wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What is the actual url of the blog you're pulling from? Does that blog have any posts?

Comment: have you dropped a break point on the line in the for loop to see what is in `thefeeds[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, you should include brackets in your for-loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++) {
  rssoutput+="<li><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a>" + thefeeds[i].content +"</li>"
}
```

I'm not sure if this is causing your problem or not. You may have some browser compatibility issues without the brackets.

You should also include semicolons at the end of every statement.

I managed to get your code working by changing the blog URL to an active Blogspot blog. I had to add

```
<div id="blog-feed"></div>
```

above your javascript.

Comment: Upon further digging, it looks like it's an issue with the Google Feed API and Blogger not passing all of the info to it. When debugging and viewing the raw RSS I can see the content, but when viewing what the script returns it is empty. The code above is working as intented for RSS feeds from Wordpress, it's only Blogger not working. I'll just go with the titles and links for now - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Upon further digging, it looks like it's an issue with the Google Feed API and Blogger not passing all of the info to it. When debugging and viewing the raw RSS I can see the content, but when viewing what the script returns it is empty. The code above is working as intended for RSS feeds from Wordpress, it's only Blogger not working. I'll just go with the titles and links for now - thank you!